# What word can I use to express "from No. X until the end of the serial number"?

Tags: word-usage

I am not a Native English Person.

What word can I use in the context of a consequential Serial Number? For example, I want to say: "From video No. 65 ahead" with the meaning of " The videos from No. 65 until the end of the videos' Serial Number". So, what is the appropriate word to use instead of the word "ahead" in this Context?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the word you're looking for is "onwards".

> ### onwards
>
> /ˈɒnwədz/
>
> *adverb*
>
> 1. **​from… onwards** continuing from a particular time
>
> - They lived there from the 1980s onwards.
> - The pool is open from 7 a.m. onwards.
>
> 2. ​(formal) forward
>
> - We drove onwards towards the coast.

([Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/onwards))

Therefore, an appropriate phrase would be "from video no. 65 onwards".